# How can I retrieve all google Contacts with the Contacts API?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to use the Contacts API to retrieve all the contacts of the person who clicks on the `<a>` at the bottom of response-callback.php. I am using Google App Engine and within the GAE I enabled the Contacts API. I got this code by following a tutorial so it's rather hard to find errors myself. I haven't worked with either PHP or GAE or any API. This also why I can't debug and check if certain values are empty are not.

When I start the website up. I doesn't show anything. Not even the echo I am using to test if I can reach the response-callback.php nor the H2 is showing I just get a completely white page.

app.yaml:

```
application: csimporttest
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /
  script: main.php;
```

main.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Hi! Stackoverflow!</h2>
<?php include'response-callback.php';
echo "response-callback file: " $test; 
?>

</body>

</html>
```

response-callback.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/autoload.php';

$test = 'WORKS!'; 

$google_client_id = 'SECRET';
$google_client_secret = 'SECRET';
$google_redirect_uri = 'SECRET';

//setup new google client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('csimporttest');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');

$client -> setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');

$googleImportUrl = $client -> createAuthUrl();
function curl($url, $post = "") {
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
 if ($post != "") {
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 }
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
 //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
 //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['google_code'])) {
 $auth_code = $_SESSION['google_code'];
 $max_results = 200;
    $fields=array(
        'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
        'client_id'=>  urlencode($google_client_id),
        'client_secret'=>  urlencode($google_client_secret),
        'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($google_redirect_uri),
        'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
    );
    $post = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $post = rtrim($post,'&');
    $result = curl('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',$post);
    $response =  json_decode($result);
    $accesstoken = $response->access_token;
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
    $xmlresponse =  curl($url);
    $contacts = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);

 $return = array();
 if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
 foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
           //retrieve Name and email address  
 $return[] = array (
 'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
 'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
 );
 } 
 }

 $google_contacts = $return;

 unset($_SESSION['google_code']);

}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $googleImportUrl; ?>"> Import google contacts </a>
```

Comment: A completely white page? That would be the _White Screen of Death_. See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914127/white-screen-of-death) for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an var_dump() to see if the array google_contacts is actually filled.  Put this in the main.php:

```
 <?php
var_dump($google_contacts);
?>
```

If you get an output in the var_dump you can use an html table and an easy foreach, look below:

```
<table border='1' class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Naam </th>
    <th>Email </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($google_contacts as $contacts){
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['name']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'. $contacts['email'].'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>

</table>
```