# White Screen of Death, Twig_Node_Expression _Constant not found

Tags: php, linux, xampp, twig, lampp

I had a site that I was making in XAMPP in windows environment which was and still is working fine. However I have switched it over to LAMP using linux. And now I getting a white screen of death. I read up [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) that I should use this code;

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

at the top of my index.php file to display errors. Which I have done but now get the error;

```
Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Node_Expression_Constant' not found in /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php on line 206
```

I am not to sure how to fix this as this file is in the vendor folder. As mentioned before it seems to work fine on XAMPP in windows but on linux I keep getting this error and a white screen. I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914127/white-screen-of-death) but these links just seemed to say the same thing as the first link I visited to display the errors

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/provider/AuthenticationServiceProvider.php';
require_once 'src/provider/TutorServiceProvider.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Tutor\Provider\AuthenticationServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Tutor\Provider\TutorServiceProvider());

$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
    $tutors = $app['tutor']->get_tutors();
    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', array('active_page' => 'home', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'tutors' => $tutors));
});

$app->get('/about-us', function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('about-us.twig', array('active_page' => 'about-us', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->get('/home-tuition', function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('home-tuition.twig', array('active_page' => 'home-tuition', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->get('/group-tuition', function() use($app) {
    $groups = $app['tutor']->get_group_tuition($app['auth']->get_user()['email']);
    return $app['twig']->render('group-tuition.twig', array('active_page' => 'group-tuition', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'groups' => $groups, 'user' => $app['auth']->get_user()));
});

$app->get('/group-tuition/{tutoremail}/{starttime}', function($tutoremail, $starttime) use($app) {
    $user = $app['auth']->get_user();
    if (null !== $user && ($user['type'] == 'admin' || $user['email'] == $tutoremail)) {
        $group = $app['tutor']->get_group_tuition_details($tutoremail, $starttime);
        return $app['twig']->render('group-tuition-details.twig', array('active_page' => 'group-tuition', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'group' => $group));
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/group-tuition');
    }
});

$app->get('/contact-us', function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('contact-us.twig', array('active_page' => 'contact-us', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->get('/tutor/{username}', function($username) use($app) {
    $tutor = $app['tutor']->get_tutor($username);
    if (null !== $tutor) {
        return $app['twig']->render('tutor.twig', array('active_page' => 'tutor', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'tutor' => $tutor));
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    }
});

$app->get('/login', function() use($app) {
    if ($app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array('active_page' => 'login', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
    }
});

$app->post('/login', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $email = $app['request']->get('email');
    $password = $app['request']->get('password');
    if ($app['auth']->login($email, $password)) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/login');
    }
});

$app->get('/logout', function() use($app) {
    $app['auth']->logout();
    return $app->redirect('/');
});

$app->get('/register', function() use($app) {
    if ($app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app['twig']->render('register.twig', array('active_page' => 'register', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
    }
});


$app->post('/register', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $email = $app['request']->get('email');
    $password = $app['request']->get('password');
    $name = $app['request']->get('name');
    $address = $app['request']->get('address');
    $phone = $app['request']->get('phone');
    if ($app['auth']->register($email, $password, $name, $address, $phone, 'student')) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/register');
    }
});



$app->get('/reset-password', function() use($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('reset-password.twig',array('active_page' => 'reset-password','is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->post('/reset-password', function(Request $request) use($app){
    $email = $app['request']->get('email');
    if($app['auth']->sendEmail($email)){
        return $app->redirect('/');
    }else{
        return $app->redirect('/reset-password');
    }
});

$app->get('/admin', function() use($app) {
    $tutor = $app['tutor']->get_tutors();
    $user = $app['auth']->get_user();
    if (null !== $user && $user['type'] == 'admin' && null !== $tutor){
        return $app['twig']->render('admin.twig', array('active_page' => 'admin', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'contacts' => $app['tutor']->get_user(), 'items' => $app['tutor']->get_user_id(), 'tutor' => $tutor));
    }else{
        return $app->redirect('/login');
    }
});



$app->post('/charge', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $description = $app['request']->get('description');
    $tutoremail = $app['request']->get('tutoremail');
    $starttime = $app['request']->get('starttime');
    $user = $app['auth']->get_user();
    $studentemail = $user['email'];

    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_fktchFYkd0XywraJftt8Z9uc");

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $token = $app['request']->get('stripeToken');

    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 2000, // amount in cents, again
            "currency" => "gbp",
            "source" => $token,
            "description" => $description . ' paid by ' . $studentemail . ' for session ' . $tutoremail . '/' . $starttime
        ));
        $app['tutor']->add_group_tuition_booking($tutoremail, $starttime, $studentemail);
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // The card has been declined
    }
    return $app->redirect('/group-tuition');
});

$app->run();

?>
```

Composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.1",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "~2.3",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3",
        "symfony/config": "^3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.3",
        "symfony/filesystem": "~2.3",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.3",
        "symfony/form": "^3.0",
        "symfony/locale": "~2.3",
        "symfony/process": "~2.3",
        "symfony/security": "~2.3",
        "symfony/serializer": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "^3.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.3",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": ">=2.2.0,<2.4.0-dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.24",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "^3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

After reading around a lot over the internet I managed to solve both problem.

1) For the first problem I was copying over the `composer.json` file and `vendor` directory just expecting them to work. However as mentioned in the comments above by @Federico I simply copied over my `composer.json` file and ran composer update. This solved the `TWIG_NODE_EXPRESSION_CONSTANT` error.

2) The second error I mentioned was that I was getting a 404 when navigating to other pages;

For this I read around the internet and learnt that you need to edit the httpd.conf file to get the htaccess file to work with apache. However as I have a different version of ubuntu which meant the `apache2.conf` file (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`), so I changed the code;

from this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However after this I was still getting an 500 internal error. So I found out that the `/etc/apache2/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (on some versions maybe `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` this was not the case on the ubuntu 14.04 that I am using) needs to have the above code inserted into it aswell. However as I installed lamp according to ubuntu's instructions this `/etc/apache2/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file was copied over to `/etc/apache2/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf` and this is where I added in the code;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This finally got it to work. Not sure why apache changed their directory/files conventions around guess its to do with different version upgrades.

Comment: how did you installed twig? with composer? have you included his autoloader?

Comment: yes installed twig with composer. I have required the vendor autoload at the top of my index file. I will post my index.php file up now

Comment: can you run `composer update` to regenerate the class maps and show us your `composer.json` file?

Comment: have run update, composer.json file is now up there.

Comment: ok managed to get rid of the white screen and error by removing and reinstalling twig. It brings up my homepage however now I am getting 404 errors when I try to use the navigation to go to another page. Not sure whats going on. All of this work perfectly fine in windows