# CodeIgniter white page while inserting a record

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

i'm using CodeIgniter with postgreSQL and i always getting a blank page when i inserting multiple records > 61 rows. I'm not sure why it is happen, inserting <= 61 rows works fine. There is no errors found in Log file. I already tried many ways to fix this problem but still have no result.

here are my references:

[Codeigniter shows blank page with no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230694/codeigniter-shows-blank-page-with-no-error)

[Codeigniter displays a blank page instead of error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages)

[Why does Code Igniter give me a white page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149321/why-does-code-igniter-give-me-a-white-page#answer-2149468)

[Codeigniter, blank page, no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165283/codeigniter-blank-page-no-errors)

http://thecancerus.com/the-white-screen-of-death/

I also already set `display_error On` in `php.ini` and set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in `index.php` file.
My sites is working on local machine Debian with Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6, PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Can you try to increase your php memory size and max execution time in php.ini and reboot apache?

Comment: php `memory_limit=512`  + `max_input_time=120` +  `max_execution_time=600` restarted web server still not working

Comment: Can you dump the raw insert of > 61 records and insert directly to eliminate mysql as the culrpit? Please post the php code that inserts the records - I would also log the response on each entry if you're looping through manually or var_dump each result.

Comment: in the controller construct add `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and see what you get.

Comment: Oh, i was solved the problem. "PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0" detected in apache log, after increased the value everything works fine.